# jQuery why this does not work $(":input").change(function(){});

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

```
$(":input").change(function() {alert("hello");}
```

Basic idea is when input changes, do the function. But it wouldn't work with IE8, when I changed some words in the input text field, the function was not triggered. This does not happen with other versions of IE(9+) or other browsers.

Comment: Which version of jQuery?

Comment: $("input").change(function() {alert("hello");} try to remove the colon in input

Comment: @VondRitz Tried that, does not work.

Comment: @Sprottenwels `.change(func)` is just a shortcut for `.on("change", func)` (or `.bind("change", func)`) depending on the version of jQuery

Comment: Propertychange worked for me.

Comment: @Bencolder Are you changing the value in JavaScript or by typing? The `propertychange` shouldn't be needed. If you're changing the value in JavaScript, use `.trigger()`: `$("#some_input_id").val("some value").trigger("change");`

Comment: @Ian I am changing the value in the input field and once javascript detects that I have some code to change other input fields' values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe its an issue with the event itself. maybe try:

```
var ie8 = /msie 8/gi.test(window.navigator.userAgent);

$("input").bind(ie8 ? 'propertychange' : 'change', function() {
   alert("hello");
}
```

**Edit
Note: Newer jQuery versions take of this themselves!**

And for lower IE8, if needed:

var lowIE = /msie (6|7|8)/gi.test(window.navigator.userAgent);

```
$("input").bind(lowIE ? 'propertychange' : 'change', function() {
   alert("hello");
}
```

Comment: you should know that newer jquery versions take care of this theirselves :)

Comment: @Alex But jQuery would not work with IE8 on version 2.0 and above.

Comment: are you sure? i cant image jquery 2+ version drop IE8 support?

Comment: Though IE8 support is not a reason to use 1.7.2. The latest 1.x release (1.10.1) supports IE8 and with some luck fixes the problem too.