# onChange is not working IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am dynamically creating a text area, based on the number of each user, comment for each user.

i am using the below code to do the same, it works fine in all the browser except IE8.

```
$(template1).find('textarea').attr({"id":'selfasgn'+aud.ASGN_ID,"onchange":'captureSelfComments('+aud.ASGN_ID+')'})
```

note that $(template1) is clone of one of the element in node.

```
template1 = reviewTemplate.clone(true);

function captureSelfComments(p_asgnid){
  alert('caling captureSelfComments');
}
```

I tried below code, but its getting called when this element gets constructed or appened to the DOM. so i removed it.

```
$(template1).find('textarea').live('change',captureSelfComments(aud.ASGN_ID))
```

am I doing anything wrong here ?

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? Also, `live` has been deprecated. You should use `on` with a delegated event handler instead.

Comment: do you use an older version of jquery which supports `.live` ?

Comment: i am using jquery 1.7

Answer (score 0):

For IE, try `propertychange()` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359952/jquery-why-this-does-not-work-input-changefunction/17360040#17360040) since IE may not always support the change event.

```
var lowIE = /msie (6|7|8)/gi.test(window.navigator.userAgent);
$(template1).find('textarea').live(lowIE ? 'propertychange' : 'change',captureSelfComments(aud.ASGN_ID));
```

Generally, it is not a good idea to do user agent sniffing but we are talking about IE... which is basically also not a good idea, generally :)

Comment: hey thanks for your answer, but this gets called on construction or append

Comment: we have a tab when clicked on tab, this cloned element is appended to the DOM. what's happening is when clicking on that tab, i get the alter of captureSelfComments

Comment: fixed it, but i am getting one error on change Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function